# Why comparisons are made between JPA, Hibernate etc

Tags: hibernate, jpa, openjpa

Although not a novice, I am still on the learning curve of JPA. As I understand, JPA is just a specification, for which there are many implementers for example: Hibernate, OpenJPA etc.

Now, I have seen many posts which ask question: "JPA VS Hibernate", "To use Hibernate or JPA" etc.

My doubt is:

1) If Hibernate is an implementation of JPA, then why are comparisons made "JPA vs Hibernate" etc.  JPA is just specification (if my understanding is correct), then what sense these comparisons make OR may be I haven't fully understood this.

Any help to clear this doubt greatly appreciated.

Comment: They're asked because people are too lazy to do their own reading. This is all documented in individual implementations, and in the answers to these other questions ... yet people keep on asking, because they don't want to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is not only a JPA implementation, but offers its own API: http://hibernate.org/orm/. Most comparisons are between the Hibernate native API and JPA API.

When using the native API there are some advanced features, but you are bound to Hibernate and you cannot switch the implementation easily like for JPA if you want to use EclipseLink instead for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, makes sense. Saw the link you mentioned, could relate it.